# What is the easiest way to get and play audio stream from RTMP server using C#?

Tags: c#, audio, rtmp

I need to write simple C# application that should be able to connect to RTMP server and play audio stream, provided by this server.
What is the easiest way to do this?
Or even better if you point me to working examples of such code.

Answer (score 0):

try this......

http://osflash.org/pipermail/red5_osflash.org/2008-November/027874.html

Comment: Thank you for the link but this library just allows to connect to RTMP server and exchange messages. 
I need some way to connect and play audio stream downloaded from there.